# How to exclude triggers from being activated/deactivated in Azure Synapse?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I currently have the following code in my yml file to activate and deactivate all of my triggers in Azure Synapse:

```
- task: toggle-triggers-dev@2
  displayName: 'Deactivate all triggers'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'qa-SPN'
    ResourceGroupName: 'qa-group'
    WorkspaceName: 'saws'
    ToggleOn: false
    Triggers: '*'

- task: toggle-triggers-dev@2
  displayName: 'Activate all triggers'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'qa-SPN'
    ResourceGroupName: 'qa-group'
    WorkspaceName: 'saws'
    ToggleOn: true
    Triggers: '*'
```

I want to activate all of my triggers except 1 and I want to know if there's any way to exclude it. The workaround is to explicitly define the toggle of each trigger but this solution won't be feasible if I have 50 triggers.

I also tried the following:

```
- task: toggle-triggers-dev@2
  displayName: 'Activate all triggers except ***'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'qa-SPN'
    ResourceGroupName: 'qa-group'
    WorkspaceName: 'saws'
    ToggleOn: true
    Triggers: 'trigger1, trigger2, trigger3'
```

But this will throw the error: `Unexpected exception or missing status code","message":"Body: {\"code\":\"TriggerNotFound\",\"message\":\"The Trigger  trigger2 was not found`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi @abautista, so do you use the above task in azure-devops pipelines? What's the name of the extension task?

Comment: I install the module `Install-Module -Name \"Az.Synapse\"`. Do I need to install an additional module? I do use this task in the azure devops pipeline

Comment: Hi @abautista, I could only find extention task [azure-synapse-toggle-triggers-json@1](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AndrewRichardsonMS.vsts-publish-synapse) in Azure devops marketplace? If it is not the extension task you used, could you share the link to download the extension task? Or does it a self-developed extension task on your side? If so please also share the package or link to download to help us do further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out -- You need to list your triggers without a space in-between:

```
Triggers: 'trigger1,trigger2,trigger3'
```